# ImportError: No module named python2x

Tags: deep-learning, theano

I'm getting the following error:

```
from theano.compat.python2x import OrderedDict .ImportError: No module named python2x
```

The "theano" API documentation states there is no compat module. Why is this?

Comment: The question seems rather broad, or perhaps more than one question. Can you be more specific on what information you are expecting?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is for later python versions to be compatible with older ones.

If you change,

`from theano.compat.python2x import OrderedDict`

to

`from collections import OrderedDict`

it should work.